# Function to find common elements of 2 lists in R, without using 'intersect'

Tags: r

I am trying to use R to create a function that takes two lists as input, and returns common elements, but without using the intersect function.  I am still struggling with a few things as I learn R:

- lists vs. vectors vs. dataframes
- how to keep/store the results from for loops and functions
- how to use sapply/mapply/etc.

Here is what I have so far.  I thought it worked at first when the only common element was '5', but when I added more common numbers it still only returns '5'.

** Note - I realized after writing this that it is only necessary to run this in one direction (is anything in list_a also in list_b) but now I'm curious how to get this version running  from a programming perspective.

---

```
a <- list(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- list(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)

a_match <- numeric()
b_match <- numeric()

ab <- function(list_a, list_b) {
  for (i in list_a) {
    results <- if(i %in% list_b) {i}
    a_in_b <- c(a_match, results)
  }
  for (i in list_b) {
    results <- if(i %in% list_a) {i}
    b_in_a <- c(b_match, results)
  }
  combined <- c(a_in_b, b_in_a)
  unique(combined)
}


ab(a, b)
```

Is there a way to use an 'apply' here? and:

1. return a vector that is not the same length as the input (limitation of sapply)
2. can take in multiple inputs that aren't the same length (limitation of mapply)

Comment: are you dealing with sets?? for example `a<- list(3, 4, list(1,2)` and `b<- list(4, list(2,1), 3)` will you consider these two to be equivalent?? setwise they are

Answer (score 0):

Your a_match and b_match is outside declared outside the function. I have fixed your example Check below:

```
a <- list(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- list(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)

ab <- function(list_a, list_b) {
  
  a_match <- numeric()
  b_match <- numeric()

  
  for (i in list_a) {
    results <- if(i %in% list_b) {i}
    a_match <- c(a_match, results)
  }
  
  for (i in list_b) {
    results <- if(i %in% list_a) {i}

    b_match <- c(b_match, results)
  }
  combined <- c(a_match,b_match)
  
  unique(combined)
}


ab(a, b)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!   Why does it matter to R whether they are declared inside or outside the function?

Comment: @kwsunshine123 This is due to scoping. All the variables inside the function should be declared inside the function or it should be passed as a parameter into the function.

Answer (score 0):

we could just use the `%in%` function to get elements that are in `a` and `b` => `a %in% b` is a logical vector we use it to subset the original list.

```r
a %in% b
#> [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
unique(a[a %in% b])
```

```
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 5
```

Mind you that most of the operators (functions) in baseR are vectorised thus no need to use the apply family in this one.

```r
unlist(unique(a[a %in% b]))
#> [1] 3 4 5
```

Comment: Thank you!!  I'm really struggling with how messy the list  output is (I assume the  output you printed is a list).  Why does it not just return a neat vector that matches the  input?

Comment: @kwsunshine123 because we're subsetting a list, if you want it to return a vector wrap it in `unlist` call. one thing that's important in R programing is using the vectorised aspect as it is optimized more than for loops and aesthetically better. Also note that this works even for children lists that are in a and b

Comment: @kwsunshine123 note that if you're gonna have a and b be nested lists add `recursive=FALSE` to the unlist call